# SimpleDateFormat returns "Sun Oct 10 00:00:00 BRT 2010" but insert "2010-10-10"

Tags: java, mysql, date, simpledateformat

i have a code  where i use a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String data = jTData.getText();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dataInserir = null;
dataInserir = formatter.parse(data);
System.out.println(dataInserir);
```

The output for this code if the string from the `jTData.getText()`is "2010-10-10" is:

```
Sun Oct 10 00:00:00 BRT 2010.
```

But, it is inserted in the database the value 2010-10-10.

The field is:

```
 @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date data;
```

What am i missing that i'm not able to get an output like `2010-10-10` as  a `Date` ?
And why is this inserting the value `2010-10-10` if the output is `Sun Oct 10 00:00:00 BRT 2010`?
Any help i'll be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Because those are the same values. A `Date` has a default format, but is internally a number of milliseconds since epoch (January 1, 1970). And `2010-10-10` **is** Sunday the 10th of October.

Comment: In this case, if i pass as a parameter `dataInserir`, the program will understand it as `2010-10-10` that is in the database?

Comment: It's probably because the data type in the database is different and automatically formatting it for its data type

Comment: If you print out using `System.print.out(formatter.format(dataInserir));` you will get the same string value as `jData.getText()`.

Comment: Well, thank all of you guys!

Comment: I believe that in most database implementations, a date column, unlike datetime or timestamp columns, does not have a time component. Since you are specifying that the type of the column is a TemporalType.DATE, you are implying that the datebase column associated with the data is a date column, and hence only a date is being saved. If you want date and time information, consider using a datetime database column and changing the temporal type to TemporalType.timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are confusing the nature of the [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class versus [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). The first is a date *and* time-of-day, the second is date-only.

You marked marked your annotation as [`javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#DATE). The doc for that enum says simply:

> Map as java.sql.Date

**You said to store a date-only.**

So what you are experiencing is a feature, not a bug.

If you want to store a date with a time-of-day, use the [javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#TIMESTAMP) annotation.

Back that with a timestamp type on the column in your database (should almost always be a timestamp-with-time-zone type).

Also, I recommend using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework rather than the troublesome java.util.Date and SimpleDateFormat classes. But that is a whole other topic.